# write html input to csv file

Tags: php, csv

I try to write from html form to csv file using php. I have a problem that nothing is wrote in the file .

I want to be like this:

> a,b,c,d

and if I have an empty input, it will be like this

> a,,b,c,d

This is the code, what's wrong on it?

```
$csv=array();
$number=$_POST['txt_number'];
$description=$_POST['txt_description'];
$division=$_POST['txt_division'];
$stage=$_POST['txt_stage'];
$category=$_POST['txt_category'];
$priority=$_POST['txt_priority'];
$frequency=$_POST['txt_frequency'];
$notapprove=$_POST['txt_notapprove'];
$approve=$_POST['txt_approve'];
$notexist=$_POST['txt_notexist'];
$wo=$_POST['txt_wo'];
$duration=$_POST['duration'];
$startdate=$_POST['startdate'];
$enddate=$_POST['enddate'];
$asd=$_POST['txt_asd'];
$add=$_POST['txt_add'];
$aduration=$_POST['txt_aduration'];
$transferredto=$_POST['txt_transferredto'];
$prb=$_POST['txt_percentage'];
$note=$_POST['txt_note'];
$projectname=$_POST['txt_projectname'];
if($exist=="Not Approve"){$a="Not Approve";}
if($exist=="Approve"){$b="Approve";}
if($exist=="Not Exist"){$c="Not Exist";}
$csv[]=$number;
$csv[]=$description;     
$csv[]=$division;
$csv[]=$stage;
$csv[]=$category;
$csv[]=$priority;
$csv[]=$frequency;
$csv[]=$notapprove;
$csv[]=$approve;
$csv[]=$notexist;
$csv[]=$wo;
$csv[]=$duration;
$csv[]=$startdate;
$csv[]=$enddate;
$csv[]=$asd;
$csv[]=$add;
$csv[]=$aduration;
$csv[]=$transferredto;
$csv[]=$prb;
$csv[]=$note;
$csv[]=$projectname;
$csv[]=$a;
$csv[]=$b;
$csv[]=$c;    

$file = fopen("contacts.csv","w");

foreach ($csv as $line)
{
  fputcsv($csv,$line);
}

fclose($file);
```

Comment: You arent pointing fputcsv to the file handle. Try to change `fputcsv($csv, $line);` to `fputcsv($file, $line);`

Comment: `fputcsv($csv,$line);` should be `fputcsv($file, $line);` and you don't need the foreach loop... just do: `fputcsv($file, $csv);` directly.

Comment: You should also get an "undefined variable" every time you run this script, since you're always using `$a`, `$b` and `$c` but you only define one of them (which depends on the contents of `$exist`).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i put it like this   $file = fopen("contacts.csv","w");
  fputcsv($file,$line);
fclose($file); but also i have an empty file

Comment: What does `$line` come from? Send in your array `$csv` instead.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i elimine $line like this $file = fopen("contacts.csv","w");
  fputcsv($file);
fclose($file); but also have an empty file

Comment: Read the comments again.. carefully. _"Send in your array $csv instead"_. `fputcsv($file, $csv);`. And please read the manual for `fputcsv()`: http://php.net/manual/fr/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i have 2 problem first problem that i have a select input and the select input value in csv file have " " ex: " a " the second the i can't enter multi line in the csv file if i submit the form the values be in csv file if i enter another input and submit the form the first be erase and the second appear

Comment: **You should definitely start reading the manuals!** `fopen()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php . You are using `fopen("contacts.csv", "w")` where `"w"` = _place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length_. You should use `"a"` instead, which appends to the current file instead of truncate it.

Comment: ok i change it to a and it's work but i want each one on on a line every time i submit the form i want the values be in one line like this a,b,c,d                                                                                                    e,f,g,h,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124208/discussion-between-mhmd-and-magnus-eriksson).

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.fputcsv.php

fputcsv() uses an array as 2nd parameter, not a string.
And the 1st parameter must be your file handler.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will create or add to contacts.csv using a comma to delimit each row;

If you wish to add a new line you can open the file using the a+ flag check if it contains a character, if it does add \n

From PHP manual on a+ Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the end of the file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it. In this mode, fseek() only affects the reading position, writes are always appended.

```
// set dummy data
$_POST['txt_number'] = "test";
$_POST['txt_description'] = "test";
$_POST['txt_division'] = "test";
$_POST['txt_stage'] = "test";
$_POST['txt_category'] = "test";
$_POST['txt_priority'] = "test";
$_POST['txt_frequency'] = "test";
$_POST['txt_notapprove'] = "test";
$_POST['txt_approve'] = "test";
$_POST['txt_notexist'] = "test";
$_POST['txt_wo'] = "test";
$_POST['duration'] = "test";
$_POST['startdate'] = "test";
$_POST['enddate'] = "test";
$_POST['txt_asd'] = "test";
$_POST['txt_add'] = "test";
$_POST['txt_aduration'] = "test";
$_POST['txt_transferredto'] = "test";
$_POST['txt_percentage'] = "test";
$_POST['txt_note'] = "test";
$_POST['txt_projectname'] = "test";
$_POST['txt_priority'] = "low pri";

// open the file with a+ flag
$file = fopen('contacts.csv', 'a+');

// read the file and check for a character
if( fread($file, 1) != "" ){

    // file has data, write new line
    fwrite($file, "\n");

}

// build csv array
$csv=array();
$csv[] = $_POST['txt_number'];
$csv[] = $_POST['txt_description'];
$csv[] = $_POST['txt_division'];
$csv[] = $_POST['txt_stage'];
$csv[] = $_POST['txt_category'];
$csv[] = $_POST['txt_priority'];
$csv[] = $_POST['txt_frequency'];
$csv[] = $_POST['txt_notapprove'];
$csv[] = $_POST['txt_approve'];
$csv[] = $_POST['txt_notexist'];
$csv[] = $_POST['txt_wo'];
$csv[] = $_POST['duration'];
$csv[] = $_POST['startdate'];
$csv[] = $_POST['enddate'];
$csv[] = $_POST['txt_asd'];
$csv[] = $_POST['txt_add'];
$csv[] = $_POST['txt_aduration'];
$csv[] = $_POST['txt_transferredto'];
$csv[] = $_POST['txt_percentage'];
$csv[] = $_POST['txt_note'];
$csv[] = $_POST['txt_projectname'];
$csv[] = $_POST['txt_priority'];

// set empty output string
$sOutput = "";

// loop through each array entry, concatonating a comma each time if output isnt empty (after first pass)
foreach ($csv as $sLine) {
    if($sOutput != "") $sOutput .= ",";
    $sOutput .= $sLine;
}

// write the output string to the file
fwrite($file, $sOutput);

// close file
fclose($file);
```

This Writes the following to contacts.csv;

```
test,test,test,test,test,low pri,test,test,test,test,test,test,test,test,test,test,test,test,test,test,test,low pri
```

Comment: i have 2 problem first problem that i have a select input and the select input value in csv file have " " ex: " a " the second the i can't enter multi line in the csv file if i submit the form the values be in csv file if i enter another input and submit the form the first be erase and the second appear

Comment: Problem 1; so you have a select box that will result in the value a,b or c coming through? Could I have the name given to the select? Problem 2: Can you confirm the issue is, on resubmitting the form it looses the data in the csv file created?

Comment: <select id="selectbasic" name="txt_priority" class="form-control">
        <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Low Priority">Low Priority</option>
   <option value="Routine">Routine</option>
      <option value="Urgent">Urgent</option>
       <option value="Important">Important</option>
    </select>

Comment: if i want to enter another line to csv file using the html form i can't the first line be deleted and the second line appear

Comment: the problem is if i use \r or \n the "," disappear and i need this

Comment: and also i have the problem of " " for the select field

Comment: can you not just add an extra ","? Also for the select field, echo it out to see if you are receiving it correctly.

Comment: i want "," between the word like this a,b,c

Comment: I'm sorry I dont understand. What I have supplied will split each element added to the array by a comma. Please update your question or create a new one if this has solved some of your issues

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124218/discussion-between-mhmd-and-atoms).

Answer (score 0):

Change from

```
foreach ($csv as $line)
{
  fputcsv($csv,$line);
}
```

to

```
fputcsv($file,$csv);
```

**For multiline use**

```
fputcsv($file,$csv,"\n");
```

or

```
fputcsv($file,$csv,"\r");
```

**For append in csv use**

```
$file = fopen("contacts.csv","a");
```

Comment: i have 2 problem first problem that i have a select input and the select input value in csv file have " " ex: " a " the second the i can't enter multi line in the csv file if i submit the form the values be in csv file if i enter another input and submit the form the first be erase and the second appear

Comment: @mhmd solution added for your both problem

Comment: replace \n with \r and check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124210/discussion-between-mhmd-and-dhruv-jadia).

Comment: so you have to apply it with every field like fputcsv($file,$fieldname,'\r')