# Insert into csv file with a new line each

Tags: php, file, csv

I try to insert data from a form into a csv file the insert work fine but i have a problem with the new line i did different search and have different solution but nothing work for me

this is the code

```
$file = fopen('contacts.csv', 'a+');
// open the file and check for a character
if( fread($file, 1) != "" ){
// file has data, write new line
fwrite($file, "\n");
}else{
// file doesnt have data, no new line needed
}
$csv=array();
$csv[] = $_POST['txt_number'];
$csv[] = $_POST['txt_stage'];
$csv[] = $_POST['txt_category'];     
$csv[] = $_POST['txt_description'];
$csv[] = $_POST['txt_division'];
$csv[] = $_POST['txt_notapprove'];
$csv[] = $_POST['txt_approve'];
$csv[] = $_POST['txt_notexist'];
$csv[] = $_POST['txt_priority'];
$csv[] = $_POST['txt_frequency'];
$csv[] = $_POST['startdate'];
$csv[] = $_POST['enddate'];
$csv[] = $_POST['duration']; 
$csv[] = $_POST['txt_asd'];
$csv[] = $_POST['txt_add'];
$csv[] = $_POST['txt_aduration'];
$csv[] = $_POST['txt_transferredto'];     
$csv[] = $_POST['txt_wo'];
$csv[] = $_POST['txt_percentage'];
$csv[] = $_POST['txt_note'];
// put data stored in $csv into file
fputcsv($file,$csv);
fclose($file);
```

the out put i want in the file is like this example

`,,,test,test,,,,,,`   new line for a new date

```
,,,test2,test2,,,,,
```

i used different thing `"\n","\r","\n\r"` 
but this solution didn't work
once it give me the result with new line without cama `","` and that what i don't want 
than how to solve this problem to a new line in a csv file in the look i want ?

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="textinput">Description</label>  
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input id="textinput" name="txt_description" type="text" placeholder="Description" class="form-control input-md">
    </div>
     <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="textinput">Division</label>  
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input id="textinput" name="txt_division" type="text" placeholder="Division" class="form-control input-md" >
    </div></div>
    <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="textinput">Stage</label>  
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input id="textinput" name="txt_stage" type="text" placeholder="Stage" class="form-control input-md" >
    </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="textinput">Category</label>  
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input id="textinput" name="txt_category" type="text" placeholder="Category" class="form-control input-md" >
  </div>
      <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="radios">Priority</label>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <select id="selectbasic" name="txt_priority" class="form-control">
        <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Low Priority">Low Priority</option>
      <option value="Routine">Routine</option>
      <option value="Urgent">Urgent</option>
       <option value="Important">Important</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  </div>
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="textinput">Frequency</label>  
  <div class="col-sm-3">
  <select id="selectbasic" name="txt_frequency" class="form-control">
    <option value=""></option>
   <option value="Once">Once</option>  
      <option value="Daily">Daily</option>
      <option value="Weekly">Weekly</option>
      <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
       <option value="Semiannual">Semiannual</option>      
</select>
  </div>
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="textinput">Transferred To</label>  
  <div class="col-sm-3">
      <?php
      $q=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT concat(db_fname,' ' , db_lname) as fname from tbl_user where db_level!='4'
      UNION 
      SELECT db_CompanyName as scn from tbl_supplier 
      UNION 
      SELECT db_CompanyName as sucn from tbl_subcontractor

      ")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
      echo'<select name="txt_transferredto" class="form-control inpu-md" >';
     echo"<option value=''></option>";
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
         $fname=$row['fname'];
         $companyname=$row['scn'];
         $subcompanyname=$row['sucn'];
      if($fname!=""){
       echo"<option value='$fname'>";echo $fname;echo"</option>";}
    else if($subcompanyname!=""){      
        echo"<option value='$subcompanyname'>";echo $subcompanyname;echo"</option>";}
    else if($companyname!=""){      
        echo"<option value='$companyname'>";echo $companyname;echo"</option>";}
      }

      echo'</select>';
      ?>

    </div>
     <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="textinput">WO</label>  
  <div class="col-sm-3">
<input id="textinput" name="txt_wo" type="text" placeholder="WO" class="form-control input-md">  
  </div>

 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="checkbox">Not Approve</label>
     <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type = 'Radio' Name ='exist' value= 'Not Approve' >

     </div>
      <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="checkbox">Approve</label>
     <div class="col-sm-3">
 <input type = 'Radio' Name ='exist' value= 'Approve'>
     </div>
      <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="checkbox">Not Exist</label>
     <div class="col-sm-3">
     <input type = 'Radio' Name ='exist' value= 'Not Exist' >
     </div>
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="textinput">Percentage</label>  
  <div class="col-sm-3">
<input id="textinput" name="txt_percentage" type="text" placeholder="Percentage" class="form-control input-md">  
  </div>
 </div>
 <!--Planing Date-->
  <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="textinput">Planing Start Date</label>  
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input id="basic_example_1" name="startdate" type="text" placeholder="planing Date" class="form-control input-md" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="(this.type='text')" onChange="onDateChange()" onchange="cal()">
  </div>
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="textinput">Planing DUE Date</label>  
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input id="basic_example_2" name="enddate" type="text" placeholder="planing Date" class="form-control input-md" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="(this.type='text')" onchange="cal()" > 
  </div>
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="textinput" >Duration</label>
 <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input id="duration" name="duration" type="text" placeholder="Duration" class="form-control input-md" onChange="onDateChange()" >
  </div>
  </div>
  <!--Actual Date -->
  <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="textinput">Actual Start Date</label>  
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input id="basic_example_3" name="txt_asd" type="text" placeholder="Actual Date" class="form-control input-md" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="(this.type='text')" onChange="onDateChange()" onchange="call()" >
  </div>
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="textinput">Actual DUE Date</label>  
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input id="basic_example_4" name="txt_add" type="text" placeholder="Actual Date" class="form-control input-md" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="(this.type='text')"  onchange="call()" >
  </div>
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="textinput" >Duration</label>
 <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input id="aduration" name="txt_aduration" type="text" placeholder="Duration" class="form-control input-md" onChange="onDateChange()" >
  </div>
  </div>
  <!--progress Bar-->


  <!-- Textarea -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="textarea">Notes</label>
  <div class="col-md-9">                     
    <textarea class="form-control" id="textarea" name="txt_note" ></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Button (Double) -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="button1id"></label>
  <div class="col-md-8">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success">
  </div>
```

Comment: Could you please post the current output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a new line to a CSV file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399197/add-a-new-line-to-a-csv-file)

Comment: @PatrickMlr the out put without \n is ,,,test,test,,,,,,,,,test2,test2,,,,,         with \n is testtest   new line test2test2

Comment: @Anton sorry i say i did a lot of search from 3 days and i didn't have a solution for that i post now here

Comment: Isn't this more or less the same question you posted a couple of days ago? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39701823/write-html-input-to-csv-file

Comment: @MagnusEriksson the problem in this question is to write in a csv file not the new line

Comment: @mhmd, I have tried your code & every time i have run the script it wrote the data new line.try to open your .csv file from cmd.

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu you think maybe this problem is from the localhost?

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu i tried online the same problem

Comment: No, localhost has nothing to do with it.. This code works for me as well. You could actually try to read the documentation for `fputcsv()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php where they do mention new lines. (I think I recommended that a couple of days ago as well).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson but i used and it didn't work

Comment: Or you on a Mac? If you are, did you do this? (from the doc): _"Note: If PHP is not properly recognizing the line endings when reading files either on or created by a Macintosh computer, enabling the auto_detect_line_endings run-time configuration option may help resolve the problem."_

Comment: @MagnusEriksson no i use windows on my pc

Comment: Well, no one have been able to reproduce this error (which you did mention in your previous question as well). The code works for everyone that tested it. I would say that there are something else going on that we don't know about.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124494/discussion-between-mhmd-and-magnus-eriksson).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson can you please edit my code maybe i do somthing wrong that i don't know

Comment: there is no such error in your code.I have just copy past & it works as expected

Comment: Seriously... *"The code works for everyone that tested it."* kind of implies that **there isn't any error to fix/edit**

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i pull put the form i don't know if here is the problem please check above

Comment: @MagnusEriksson and i try like this $csv[]="test";$csv[]="test"; and i have the same thing on the same line both

Answer (score 0):

Format your CSV as multi-dimensional array. First level index means row index, second level index means column index.

```
$csv = [
    [
        'test',
        'test',
        'test',
    ],
    [
        'test2',
        'test2',
        'test2',
    ]
];
```

To write to CSV use loop and write line by line:

```
$file = fopen('contacts.csv', 'a+');

foreach ($csv as $row) {
    fputcsv($file, $row);
}

fclose($file);
```

Than you will get output as

```
test,test,test
test2,test2,test2
```

Comment: @mhmd teaching you how to adopt information that you heave been given from multiple resources

Comment: i tried your solution foreach ($csv as $row) {     
fputcsv($file,$row);
} but nothing is insert in the csv file

Comment: He is getting the data (just one row) in a POST. This is only valid if he has all rows in the current request.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are needing the fields in a different order in the csv than they appear in the form or I have missed the point here then the following works - every time the form is submitted it writes a new line with the $_POST data.

```
$filename = __DIR__ . '/contacts.csv';
$file = fopen( $filename, 'a+' );
fputcsv( $file, $_POST );
fclose( $file );
```

To test that each entry is on a new line, after the above code try adding:

```
$lines=file( $filename );
foreach( $lines as $line )echo $line.'<br />';
```

That shows each line being rendered with a `br` tag afterwards so you can assume that the line endings are being recognised correctly and that you should therefore be able to use that to enter to the db.

---

An alternative method that generates each $_POST on a new line that DOES appear correctly in Notepad.

```
$filename=__DIR__.'/contacts.csv';
file_put_contents( $filename, '"' . implode( '","', $_POST ). '"' . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | FILE_TEXT );
```

Comment: sorry but also that didn't work in the same line in the file

Comment: @mhmd - A question, how are you checking the file? Do you open it in notepad?

Comment: it's open in Notepad++ rather than standard notepad

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yes i do i open the file on notepad

Comment: In standard notepad it does appear as a single line

Comment: @mhmd - Notepad === infamous for not displaying all (\n) line breaks properly. Open the file in a proper text editor and you will most likely see line breaks.

Comment: @RamRaider - It does appear as a single line when I open it in Notepad. (Although, I'm using linux for creating the file).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson and this make a problem if i want than to insert the contain in mysql database ?

Comment: @mhmd - Not likely. Just test it. The new line chars are there, it's just notepad that suxx at rendering them.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson when i use \n and open on another text editor i have a new line when i use this PHP_EOL i have a new line in all but this make a problem in the two way when i want to upload to mysql database it give an empty line between each 2 line this empty line is the \n or the PHP_EOL

Comment: @mhmd - fputcsv gives you a new line by default, don't add it yourself. That means, remove all \n or PHP_EOL you have added, run the script and open it in your text editor (NOT notepad) and look.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is this code work don't use notepad to see the result if you want you can also use `PHP_EOL` it work on notepad and other editor thanks for all for your response or can you use without PHP_EOL or \n